# How to set env variables for react & go in aws ec2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, go, environment-variables

I've made React & Go product in local.
And I'm going to deploy it to AWS EC2.

To work in AWS EC2, I need to set environment variables for some secret information.

I've already set env variables for local environment. But I'm not sure about
env variables working for production environment(AWS EC2).

I already set `env.` file for local environment.
But not sure how to set environment variables in ec2.

I use environment variables for axios, firebase and mysql.

```
//axios
   const client = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    });
    client
      .get('/api/articles')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({articles: response.data});
      })
      .catch(response => console.log('ERROR!! occurred in Backend.'));
```

```
//firebases
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

```
//mysql
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        //TODO production

    }
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER")+":"+os.Getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD")+"@tcp(localhost:3306)/article")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
```

Here is the github.
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

I'm going to deploy this React & Golang product in AWS EC2.
But I'm not sure how to set environment variables.

Comment: "not sure how to set environment variables in ec2" - the same way. A virtual machine is just a machine, running an operating system. You set the environment variables however you normally would for whatever operating system it is. Type "set environment variables in " and whatever OS you're running into a search engine and you should have your answer in seconds.

Comment: typically people create a shell wrapper script on the target aws machine  which will populate the needed env vars export commands then launch your go binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use elastic beanstalk and set environment variables there.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell script you are using to launch your server on EC2, add the environment variable definition, for example :

```sh
export ENV_VAR_1=value_1
export ENV_VAR_2=value_2

... start your server ...
```

Note that this will only work for the server side.  The React App is made of Javascript running in the client's browser and you can not control the environment variables there.

If I understand well, the `Axios` code extract above is part of the React front end.  You can not have `process.env` there as this is executed on customer machine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So would you have any recommendation for client side? Axios and Firebase codes are set in client side.

Comment: I would use AWS Secret Manager to retrieve your configuration data : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html